# Calculate a field based on values repeated of an another field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I'd like to know how can i calculate in QGIS a field (field3) based on how many times a value is repeated (field2) considering an another field (field1).
For example, the field to fill with the field calculator is the "field3":

[image]

Any suggestion using the field calculator of QGIS?

Comment: Question seems unclear. What are you calculating exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I understood well (if you want to count occurrence from column `field3` or if it's the column you want to fill with a count from another column).

I have considered you want to update the `field3` using count from `field1`. In this case, you need to try the following expression to update field3 with count of occurrences from `field1` using QGIS field calculator.

```
aggregate(
 layer:=@layer,
 aggregate:='count',
 expression:="field1"
 ,filter:="field1" = attribute(
@parent, 'field1'))
```

Translated as a sentence, above code says:

For each feature, loop on all other features to filter if any match the field1 value from current line. Keep only these features. Then, count how many there are for the particular feature.

**Edit:**

What you want to do is the same as counting on multiple columns from your comment. The following do exactly what you want (tested)

```
aggregate(
 layer:=@layer,
 aggregate:='count',
 expression:="field1" || "field2"
 ,filter:="field1" || "field2" = attribute(
@parent, 'field1') || attribute(
@parent, 'field2'))
```

PS: for an unknown reason, I got crash after crash while using the recipe with virtual field but not when calculating to fill an existing or new column.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the reply. Unfortunately, your solution it doesn't work. The expected result is yet in"field3" in the image attached as example. I should consider the repetition of the values in field2 based on field1.

Comment: Edited based on your feedback. Able to calculate field3 from field1 and field2

Comment: Perfect! It works!!